# Script simples para saber quantos usuários estão online no site?

Tags: php, mysql, websocket

Amigos, existe algum script simples em php (ou alguma outra solução para servidor linux php/mysql) para saber quantos usuários estão online no site? Eu li que websocket é bom para chats. No meu caso, não é chat nem nada complexo não. Apenas saber mesmo algo como:

"xx usuários online neste momento".

Também não precisa ser a cada segundo, hehehe, mas tipo, a cada 1 minuto ou a melhor média entre tempo e não-sobrecarga do servidor.

Esta questão de não sobrecarregar o servidor com requisições é importante. Queria saber se tem alguma solução simples que exija o mínimo possível do servidor e transferência de dados (estou usando hospedagem compartilhada por enquanto). A expectativa é já ter um script que possa atender futuramente uma demanda enorme de visitantes ao mesmo tempo sem sobrecarregar o servidor (quando chegar a isso, já espero estar com servidor dedicado).

Qualquer ajuda é válida! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Tem [esse tutorial](https://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/who-is-online-widget-php-mysql-jquery) que pode auxiliar. A cada nova visita, esse código armazena os dados do visitantes e remove os registros "antigos". Depois ele captura o total utilizando o próprio "sql"

Answer (score 3):

Fazer um contador de usuários online no site, por mais simples que seja, é uma tarefa com um certo nível de complexidade. Além de ter que fazer uma programação meio trabalhosa em sincronia de JavaScript com PHP e usar banco de dados, terá que fazer controle de IP, saber quando um usuário entrou ou saiu do site etc.

Se deseja uma solução fácil para depois tentar algo próprio ou mais robusto, sugiro usar o [**Supercounters**](http://www.supercounters.com/onlinecounter). É um webservice gratuito e não precisa de cadastro. Basta inserir em seu site um pequeno código gerado no serviço, algo assim:

```
<!-- BEGIN: Powered by Supercounters.com -->
<center>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//widget.supercounters.com/ssl/online_t.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">sc_online_t(1467207,"Users Online","170ddb");</script>
<br><noscript><a href="http://www.supercounters.com/">Free Users Online Counter</a></noscript>
</center>
<!-- END: Powered by Supercounters.com -->
```

Este código irá mostrar quantos usuários estão online, e também disponibiliza um link onde você tem um relatório sobre os acessos: país do usuário, origem do acesso (*referer*), número de acesso por dia, a hora do acesso, o SO do usuário, resolução de tela, navegador (browser) entre outros.