# Contador de Visitas

Tags: php, html, html5

Quero criar um contador de visitas online no meu site, porém não sei por onde começar, pesa muito o banco de dados? como iniciar?

Comment: Dá uma olhada, talvez possa lhe interessar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/267430/8063

Comment: Eu vi essa postagem, porém não quero contador de outro site, porque to criando um portal com área administrativa, queria as estatísticas do site no painel.

Comment: Eu uso SESSION. Vejo se a SESSION não existe e envio pro banco um comando para acrescentar +1 nas visitas. Como a SESSION dura apenas alguns minutos, se o usuário ficar navegando no site dentro do tempo limite da SESSION, não envio nada pro banco, a visita dele será computada como 1 enquanto a SESSION estiver viva.

Comment: Você quer contar visitas "únicas", eu presumo.

Answer (score 4):

Existem bons serviços que já fazem isto, como o *Google Analytics*, que além de lhe dar o total de visitas em tempo real também irá lhe fornecer:

- Visitas de dias anteriores
- Visitas por tecnologia (se é mobile ou desktop)
- Visitas por região e país
- Origem das visitas (a partir de onde que o usuário encontrou seu site)

Também vai poder seguir os passos dos usuários até que eles cheguem no objetivo desejado e com isto avaliar como melhorar a navegação para facilitar que o usuário chegue até aonde você deseja, tipo finalizar uma compra, ou enviar um formulário, etc.

### Configurando gtag.js:

1. Inicie sessão na sua conta do Analytics.
2. Clique em <kbd>Admin</kbd>.
3. Selecione uma conta a partir do menu na coluna CONTA.
4. Selecione uma propriedade a partir do menu na coluna PROPRIEDADE.
5. Em PROPRIEDADE, clique em Informações de acompanhamento > Código de acompanhamento. O ID de acompanhamento é apresentado na parte superior da página.
6. Fragmento do código de acompanhamento
7. Cole o seguinte fragmento imediatamente a seguir à etiqueta `<head>` em cada página do site. **Substitua `GA_TRACKING_ID`** pelo seu próprio `ID` de acompanhamento do Google Analytics:

   ```
   <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_TRACKING_ID"></script>
   <script>

   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
     function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
     gtag('js', new Date());

     gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID');
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Existem dois tipos de analise que você querer fazer o contador, tentar contar usuário únicos, ou tentar contar o numero total de acessos, pra isso você pode usar teste de **cookies** ou **session** respectivamente.

Para contar com cookies:

```
$access_test = isset($_COOKIE["access_test"]) ? $_COOKIE['access_test'] : null;

if($access_test != true){
    setcookie("access_test",true);
    //Aqui você adiciona mais um ao campo do contador no banco de dados
}
```

Ou para contar de forma geral:

```
session_start();

$access_test = isset($_SESSION['access_test']) ? $_SESSION['access_test'] : null ;

if($access_test != true){
    $_SESSION['access_test'] = true;
    //Aqui você adiciona mais um ao campo do contador no banco de dados
}
```

**OBS:**

A contagem não é 100% precisa, basta o usuário atualizar a pagina limpando o cache que será contado mais um, porém não tem como saber com precisão sem ter registro de cada usuário do site.